# PowerShell Select-String Parameter Error

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line

I am attempting to parse a text document for a pattern with the goal of eliminating the whole line containing the pattern AND its previous line. This command-line is what I have so far that does NOT exclude, but it does return the data I WANT excluded:

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:users\example\Desktop\460-est-5.txt' | Select-String -Pattern "THE PREVIOUS" SimpleMatch -AllMatches -Context 1,0
```

Now that I have isolated the data I wish to eliminate using the previous command, I add the `NotMatch` parameter to cmdline, and it queries ALL the data in the document :(

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:users\example\Desktop\460-est-5.txt' | Select-String -Pattern "THE PREVIOUS" -SimpleMatch -NotMatch -AllMatches -Context 1,0
```

To test a theory, I go back and eliminate the parameter `-Context 1,0` and the command purges the whole line of the selected pattern, EXCEPT for the previous line.

The parameter `-Context 1,0` has been defeating the parameter `-NotMatch`, and I have dug through the help files, MSDN, StackOverflow, and I haven't found any data showing I cannot have both `context 1,0` and `NotMatch`. I am at a loss. At this point; maybe a script could get the job done? but I have no knowledge of scripting.

I have added a before and after of the data I am parsing below, reflecting what I desire; before and after. I am new to Power Shell, any advice or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Original data:

```
 A0000   FMC        18001 0000  18009 0820    200.3     
---------------------------------------------------            
 A0000   TRAN       18001 0000  00000 0000    744.0 
---------------------------------------------------                    
          *****  THE PREVIOUS STATUS IS NON-REPORTABLE  *****
---------------------------------------------------            
 A0000   FMC        18031 1600  00000 0000      8.0   
---------------------------------------------------                   
 A0000   PMCM       18031 1200  18031 1600      4.0             
---------------------------------------------------            
 A0000   FMC        18017 1303  18031 1200    334.9  
---------------------------------------------------                           
 A0000   NMCM       18017 0700  18017 1303      6.1
---------------------------------------------------                        
 A0000   FMC        18001 0000  18017 0700    391.0
---------------------------------------------------                            
 A0000   TRAN       18001 0000  00000 0000    744.0
---------------------------------------------------                             
          *****  THE PREVIOUS STATUS IS NON-REPORTABLE  *****
---------------------------------------------------            
 A0000   FMC        18017 2200  00000 0000    338.0
---------------------------------------------------                             
 A0000   PMCM       18017 1410  18017 2200      7.8  
---------------------------------------------------
```

Modified data:

```
 A0000   FMC        18001 0000  18009 0820    200.3     
---------------------------------------------------                        
 A0000   FMC        18031 1600  00000 0000      8.0   
---------------------------------------------------                   
 A0000   PMCM       18031 1200  18031 1600      4.0             
---------------------------------------------------            
 A0000   FMC        18017 1303  18031 1200    334.9  
---------------------------------------------------                           
 A0000   NMCM       18017 0700  18017 1303      6.1
---------------------------------------------------                        
 A0000   FMC        18001 0000  18017 0700    391.0
---------------------------------------------------                                       
 A0000   FMC        18017 2200  00000 0000    338.0
---------------------------------------------------                             
 A0000   PMCM       18017 1410  18017 2200      7.8  
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ooohhh...so are those dash lines in the data that you are parsing?

Comment: No they aren't. I added those in as formatting because the data stacks perfectly like that in the document but when I paste it here, it won't align properly. I should've mentioned that.

Comment: I think what I posted should work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So there is probably some slick solution but I'm a little hung over right now so I'll give you a not so slick solution:

```
# Load the file contents into memory
$data = Get-Content -Path 'C:users\example\Desktop\460-est-5.txt'
# Get the line numbers for the lines that match the search pattern
$badLines = $data | Select-String 'THE PREVIOUS' | Select-Object -expand LineNumber
# For every line number that was found, add that number minus one to the array of bad lines so those lines are on the naughty list too.
$badLines | %{$badLines += ($_-1)}
# Make a collection that will hold just the good lines
$result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$count = 1
foreach($line in $data){
  # For each line in the file, if it's line number is *not* on the naughty list, then add it to the collection of good lines
  if($badLines -notContains $count){
    $result.Add($line) | Out-Null
  }
  $count++
}
$result
```

Comment: Wow, I wish I could produce this hung over! I will test it soon and get back with you. Thank you for taking the time to generate this!

Comment: I have tested it and it worked, of course. Thank you for taking the time to generate this! I will study how it works to better understand. Thank you again!

Comment: `$result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` should simply be `$result = @()`

Comment: Arraylists are faster than arrays for adding elements